# Is $y=5 $ a plane in $\Bbb{R}^3$?

Tags: vector-analysis, 3d

I suppose it depends on how you define the variance on $x$ and $z$, but this question seems simple to me: yes.

If $P(x,y,z)$ is the set of all points $x, y, z$ such that $y=5$, it seems clear that y=5 is a plane.

The only reason I ask is because I was challenged in vector analysis that this indeed is not a plane but all points in $\Bbb{R}^3$. Almost everyone in there agreed with our professor (who I enjoy), so I call on others to please prove me wrong or right.

I graphed 'y=5 plane' on wolframalpha and it indeed was a plane to no surprise to me, but perhaps there is a way of defining it that would allow for all $\Bbb{R}^3$, who knows.

Comment: I don't know what exactly your professor has said but obviously, $(x,y,z)=(1,2,3)$ doesn't satisfy $y=5$. You don't need to ask here in order to see this.

Comment: Thanks for the edit mathnoob, at least I tried lol. Agreed Peter. He convinced a friend of the $\Bbb{R}^3$ coverage. So I wonder what the trick is, if any. I stand my ground now as to it being a plane, but everyone thinks I'm crazy, or rude and stubborn.

Comment: I don't think that everybody thinks you are crazy and I don't think that your friends and teachers are stupid. It might simply be a miunderstanding; just ask the teacher what he means.

Comment: Yep, a hard thing to do, thanks for the suggestion. It created quite the kerfluffle in class, so I'll attempt to be tactful, confrontation is a tough thing.